# How to reload registry settings ? (compact framework on a Symbol device)

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, symbols

I have a pocket pc from the Symbol manufacturer. I would like to change programmatically the power timeouts and the backlight timeouts. The application in charge of this settings is written in C# and based on the Microsoft Compact Framework 3.5.

I achieved to change these timeouts values : I changed registry keys in
HKLM/System/CurrentControlSet/Control/Power for power timeouts
and in HKCU/ControlPanel/Backlight for backlight timeouts.

It works fine, but these settings are only applied after a soft reset of the device. I would like these settings to be applied right after my application enters the registry keys.

How can the settings in the registry be reloaded? There must be a way to achieve that, because when I'm manually setting these values with the Windows Mobile Config Panel, settings apply immediately.

Answer (score 3):

You have to notify the OS that you've made the changes - it doesn't constantly watch or load the values.  Simply broadcast a WM_SETTINGCHANGE:

```
SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, NULL,NULL);
```